# Stop Unauthenticated Cognito Identity User Pool Signup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I've been playing around with the new Cognito User Pools to manage user accounts and I'm trying to build a system where users have to log in to use the system, and new users can only be added by existing users (ie no public signup).

Currently there seems to be no way of stopping an unauthenticated user from calling signUp.  I've changed it so that the Pool doesn't allow unauthenticated users but this doesn't seem to make any difference (as setting the accessKeyId and secretAccessKey to anything makes it run).

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long time, this has been solved by the AWS team.  They have now added in an option **User sign ups allowed?**  Setting this to: **Only administrators can create users** means that no-one can just sign up to the user pool.

In order to add a user now you will need to use the aws cognito sdk and the various functions starting with 'admin' (eg. adminAddUser).

Comment: This might have worked when the answer was posted, but it does not work as intended today. I have a user pool that has signs up disabled, so only an administrators should be able to create users. I have a federation enabled with Google and if one tries to login with Google - they are automatically signed up as a new user. This feels like undesired behaviour to me.

Comment: Same for me, Did you find any solution/work around for this @NikolaPetkanski

Comment: I haven't. Cognito integration was pushed back by more pressing tasks. It is expected to become a theme later this year. I hope the issue would be solved by then.

Comment: Unfortunately, using User Pools with Federation still leaves the "Only Administrators can create users" useless.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think you are confused between an [Identity Pool](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-identity.html) and a [User Pool](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html). Cognito user pools do not have a concept of allowing or not allowing "unauthenticated" access, identity pool does.

Now to answer your actual question, Cognito user pools is an authentication provider which implicitly means that the sign up process has to be unauthenticated. There is no way to authenticate a sign up call.

Although, if your use case is to build some sort of an invite based sign up process you can use the [Lambda trigger](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html) functionality with User Pools and validate each SignUp call in the PreSignUp trigger. This validation could check the existence of a valid invitation code in the validation map and accept the call only in that case.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely getting user and identity pools confused.  It sounds like I can't really do what I want then, which is to authenticate that the user calling signup is a registered user already (and is signing up someone else).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a supported use case.